# Adding a new text box to a subform continuous form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a subform and the subform displays data from a query. It works well.  However I want to add another field to the subform, so I midified the query and added the new field, and in design view dragged a new Text box into the detail of the subform, made sure it's source was the name in the query. but it never displays when opened. I don't want to redo the subform, so is there a way to add a new text box to a continuous form?

Comment: The field doesn't show (is it Visible=False?) or it is always empty?

Comment: The field is visible = yes, and it doesn't present on the sub form. But it shows in design view on the subform.